# Unity Render Texture Artifacting

Tags: unity, gui

I'm having weird black artifacts appear on my render textures when they are transformed while the game is running.

I am using a ScrollRect as a scrolling container for buttons (the buttons are just textured quads with the same render texture applied to them). When I translate the quads while the game is running, strange black artifacts will appear on the quads themselves.

Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: Interesting to note, setting every quad inactive except for one fixed the artifacting on the only visible quad: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5uUC.png

The intensity of the artifacting seems to be related to the number of objects on-screen that use the same render texture. 5 quads active with the same render texture has a really pronounced artifacting, 3 is more subtle, 1 is visibly non-existent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure you're not doubling up your textures there? Could be plain old z-fighting.

Comment: Nope. One quad with one material per button. Removed the ScrollRect bg and it still produces the same artifacts: http://i.imgur.com/4evKkT8.png  Interesting to note though, setting every quad inactive except for one fixed the artifacting on the only visible quad: http://i.imgur.com/OInBBWs.png

Comment: Yeah, the intensity of the artifacting seems to be related to the number of objects on-screen that use the same render texture. 5 quads active with the same render texture has a really pronounced artifacting, 3 is more subtle, 1 is visibly non-existent.

Comment: The idea is to have 3D models as GUI elements in a scrolling container without actually having to have multiple 3D models instantiated for the same object. From Googling around, it doesn't seem like RenderTexture is generally used for this purpose and I might just make ortho projected models part of the UI in the scene itself.

Comment: Is the distortion always to the right side? Or just in the direction of the scroll?

Comment: The distortion fluctuates across the quad as it is scrolling: http://screencast.com/t/IAOWF10Aiz9W Yes that link does work, it just takes a century to load. I'm not a computer with screen capture software that can output to Youtube :(

Answer (score 1):

This may seems crazy, but the artifacts look like shadowing artifact! Are you sure the shadows are turned off?